# Is there any way to trigger the code behind enableModifiedFlag from CCSJ or SSJS?

Tags: xpages

If I set enableModifiedFlag property to true on my Custom Control; I see the following code at the bottom of generated Page source.

Everything works fine when user moves away from changed page; they get the alert message of "Unsaved Data"

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function view__id1__id2__id95__id98__id105_clientSide_onclick(thisEvent) {
return validateForm();

}

XSP.attachDirtyUnloadListener("This document may contain unsaved changes.");

XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:saveActionEventHandler", "view:_id1", "ondirtysave", null, true, 2);
XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:_id105", "view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:link1", "onclick", view__id1__id2__id95__id98__id105_clientSide_onclick, true, 2);
XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:_id106", "view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:link2", "onclick", null, true, 2);
XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:businessName11");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:businessName21");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:address11");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:address21");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:city1");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:cbState");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:zipCode1");

XSP.attachDirtyListener("view:_id1:_id2:_id95:_id98:phoneNumber1");

}); 

</script>
```

I have an Exit button with SSJS that unlocks the document if its locked and makes a context.redirectToPage. The problem is that this button is not triggering the code behind the enableModifiedFlag logic so users leave the page without being prompted if they want to leave with unsaved data.

Is there any way to trigger code behind enableModifiedFlag from this button using CCSJ or SSJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `XSP._isDirty()` from CSJS you can get **true** if any field was modified or **false** if no changes were done to your form.

So I added this block of code to my button under CSJS to display same default alert from XPages:

```javascript
if (XSP._isDirty()){
    if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" + "\n" + "\n" +
    "This document may contain unsaved changes." + "\n" + "\n" +
    "Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just a warning on that. XSP._isDirty is an internal call. As such there is no guarantee that the call will work as expected above in the future releases, or even be there.

Answer (score 3):

On click of the button, use below CSJS: `XSP._setDirty(false,"")`
That'll make the document as non dirty and let user navigate to other page.

Comment: Thanks Declan for your response. What I want is to trigger the warning message to the user so they can decide if they want to navigate to other page. At the moment this warning is not displayed when user click on button.

Comment: Try doing the opposite to set dirty to true: XSP._setDirty(true,""). Remember that this is client-side JS.

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik, but, it add XSP._setDirty(true,"") I will get the prompt every time I press the button.