# Stop user from navigating to another document using pager in xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat control & a pager linked to it. The page displays one record from the repeat control at a time and user uses pager to navigate to previous/next document.
User can modify the document and click save & next button to save and navigate to next document.

I want to alert user if he changes any field in the form and clicks pager to navigate without saving the changes.

Can somebody please tell me how can I do this?

Regards,

Prashant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the enableModifiedFlag property of the XPage. More details at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_pref_enablemodifiedflag.html

--

You might need to trigger the warning message yourself, using CSJS. Have a look at this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428881/785061

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I have a xpage, there is a custom control on it which has repeat control and a pager and another custom control to display the document. I tried to enable this property on page/control with pager and on the control which displays document but still cant see the message :(

Comment: You might need to trigger the message yourself. I have updated my answer.