# Auto-save doc after delete of attachment in File Download control?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am allowing deletion of attachments in the File Download control. If a user deletes an attachment and navigates away from the page (without saving), the attachment does not actually get removed.

There is an onclick event for the control, but it isn't specific to deletion. Is there a way to automatically call a .save() after deletion of an attachment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a SSJS snippet which allows to add an action to the delete function of a *FileDownload* control.

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:

    /***
     * adds an additional method to "delete action"
     * of a UIFileDownload control
     *  
     * @param UIFileDownload component
     * @author Sven Hasselbach
     * @category SSJS
     * @category UI
     * @version 0.3
     */
    function overrideFileDownloadAction( fDownload ){
        if( fDownload === null )
            return;
        rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( fDownload, fDownload );
    }

    function rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( component:javax.faces.component.UIOutput, fDownload:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileDownload  ){
        try{
            var children:java.util.List = component.getChildren();
            var it:java.util.Iterator = children.iterator();
            var curChild:javax.faces.component.UIOutput;

            while( it.hasNext() ){
                curChild = it.next();
                if( typeof( curChild ) === 'com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspEventHandler' ){

                    var group = new com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup();
                    var list = new java.util.ArrayList();
                    group.setComponent( fDownload );
                    list.add( curChild.getAction() );
                    list.add( mBinding );
                    group.setActions( list );
                    curChild.setAction(group);
                }
                rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( curChild , fDownload );
            }
        }catch(e){}    
    }

    var mBinding = facesContext.getApplication().createMethodBinding("#{javascript:document1.save()}", null );
    overrideFileDownloadAction( getComponent( 'fileDownload1' ) );
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

You have to change the code in the MethodBinding *mBinding* and the name of the *FileDownLoad* control. Please keep in mind that this code will only save the document if there are no validation problems. To disable required fields you have to add the following line of code *curChild.setDisableValidators( true );* in the *if* block.

Comment: Thanks, Sven! Worked perfectly.

Comment: this code does not work in Notes 9. I get: com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup incompatible with com.ibm.xsp.actions.DeleteAttachmentsAction.  Any ideas? What has changed in the new version?

Comment: @mike_x_: IBM has changed the internal objects of the FileDownload control. Before ND9, the action was an action group, that's why it was possible to overwrite it / append a binding to it. Now, it is an instance of *DeleteAttachmentsAction* and can not be changed anymore this way.

Comment: Thank you Sven! Is there any workaround for this? I haven't found anything until now...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the enableModifiedFlag property to ensure that the user is prompted if leaving the page without saving.

More details at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_pref_enablemodifiedflag.html

Comment: I have tried to enable this, but it does not prompt when leaving the page without saving after I delete an attachment...

Comment: Is is possible to add a CSJS event that triggers the isDirty check? See this answer for the CSJS code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10428881/785061

Comment: Sven's answer above works, but thanks for comment. I can use the 'isDirty' check in other places.