# Override the upload function of a file upload control

Tags: file-upload, xpages

I want to override the upload function of a file upload control in order to add the functionality that I need. I am trying to adapt the code from the following link to my case

[Auto-save doc after delete of attachment in File Download control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101615/auto-save-doc-after-delete-of-attachment-in-file-download-control)

by changing the type of the second parameter to *com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XSPFileUpload*, i.e.:

```
function rekOverrideFileDownloadAction( component:javax.faces.component.UIOutput,  fDownload:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XSPFileUpload ){
```

and the code in the MethodBinding mBinding and by using the name of my file upload control, i.e.:

```
 var mBinding = facesContext.getApplication().createMethodBinding("#{javascript:print('Uploaded');}", null );
overrideFileDownloadAction( getComponent( 'fileUpload1' ) );
```

Unfortunately, a javax.faces.FacesException occurs.

Can anyone help me to modify this code in order to just print this message when the user uploads a file?

Stack Trace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException
javax.faces.FacesException.<init>(FacesException.java:97)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:86)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:209)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup.invoke(ActionGroup.java:135)
com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup.invoke(ActionGroup.java:135)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:209)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

I also noticed that if I add a script to an event, e.g. onChange, so that an event handler is created no exception occurs. So I think the exception is thrown because there is no event handler and that leads to a null pointer. For now I have added the functionality I need to the onChange event and it is ok, but it would be nice if someone could tell me if there is a way to override it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, include exception stacktrace you get...

Comment: Why not to use onChange? It works. Anyway, you need to invoke full refresh in order to upload file.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I ended up with. At first, I found that snippet about file download and tried to use this approach. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? I think that it is not possibile with the snippet (it overwrites an event handler of the download link which is available for an Upload Control only).

Maybe this snippet can help you: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=replace-attachment-when-uploading-a-new-attachment

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look. I also edited the question trying to clarify it. I just want to know if there is a way to override the upload function the way the snippet shows for the delete function of fileDownload.

Comment: @kmak: The Upload control has no events/functions you can modify.

Comment: I added the functionality I needed to the onChange event and it works fine, but it's nice to know the reason why my first approach failed. Thank you for the information!