# File download control ondelete event

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am using FileUpload and FileDownload control, I want to track the attachments uploaded/deleted..I am using onchange event of FileUpload control to check if its value is being changed, if yes then I am storing some values like who changed and at what time.

Now I want to track the same info when the file is deleted from FileDownload control, can anyone please let me know how to acvhieve that. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Here's an answer that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101615/auto-save-doc-after-delete-of-attachment-in-file-download-control

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I was trying to createMethodBinding and then creating a actionGroup and attach it to the fileDownload. The link given by you helped. Thanks