# queryClose in xpages

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I want to check user while closing xpage in XPiNC and web browser before closing and document e.g. displaying message do you want to save this document or not?

or other checks on different stages of workflow.

Kindly guide me the way forward to get this event in xpages.

Thanks,
Qaiser

Comment: Does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10428881/2065611 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to trigger the code behind enableModifiedFlag from CCSJ or SSJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417149/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-the-code-behind-enablemodifiedflag-from-ccsj-or-ssjs)

Comment: In case the approach with `XSP._isDirty()` is not what you are looking for you may want to have a look at the `onbeforeunload` event in CSJS: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp . The default "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" message in the confirmation dialog can be customized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: Thanks everybody, let me go through these answers and get back to you on this.